# Can I achieve dynamic object with dynamic fields from db in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I know GraphQL is a solution but I wanted to know is there any other way around as I want this functionality just to replace DB calls where I just specify which object and its fields are required and I got those data. I don't want graphQL APIs.

For example: I have tables A, B and C, and if I have table B and C primary key as a foreign key in table A.

Let's say I am query table A data with Id 1 and then I can also include the data of table c which is linked with table A id 1 within the same query with `include(x => x.tableC)`. eg :-

```
db.Where<TableA>(x => x.id.equals(id)).include(x => x.tablec);
```

Now my requirement is like what data to include can be dynamic it can be only `TableB(FieldA, FieldB)` or it can be `TableC(FieldA), TableB(FieldA, FieldB)` or only `TableC(FieldD)`.

According to that, I want the result

And this thing what to include will be in a variable

Comment: We need a bit more detail. Can you give an example of a query you want to replace, and exactly what change you'd want to make? Are you asking how to build a SELECT statement dynamically to only select certain fields, or something? Your post is just a little bit vague at the moment.

Comment: @ADyson **edited**, hope it helps you to understand, Thanks

Comment: Ok. Well, how will the code know which tables to include each time? Will you set a variable to control that? If so, then you could use an `if` statement to decide whether to chain each include() statement to the query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from your question; and assuming that you store relation in variable so you can chain `include`:

Something like this:

```
//Lets say TableA has relation with tableB and tableC
List<string> tableARelations = new List<string>()
{
    "tableB",
    "tableC"
}


using (var dbContext = GetDbContext())
{
    var query = dbContext.TableA.AsQueryable();
    foreach (string include in tableARelations)
    {
        query = query.Include(include);
    }

    var result =  query.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();                    
}
```